Chern classes of complex manifold definition
If $X$ is a complex manifold, how are the Chern classes $c_k(X)$ defined in terms of Chern-Weil theory? In some places I see that $$c_k(X) = c_k(\mathcal{T}_X)$$ where $\mathcal{T}_X$ is the holomorphic tangent bundle and in other places that $$c_k(X) = c_k\left(\bigwedge^n \mathcal{T}_X\right)$$ where $\bigwedge^n \mathcal{T}_X$ is the top degree wedge product of $\mathcal{T}_X$.

The other places are wrong. The higher Chern classes of a line bundle are zero. The equality is OK for $k=1$, so perhaps that’s the cause of the confusion.

That was indeed the cause of confusion. Is it easy to see that for $k = 1$ these two are the same? @TedShifrin

Yes, @Rene do you know how a chern classes are defined?

Yes, the first Chern class of any bundle $E$ should be given by $c_1(E) = [i/2\pi \text{tr} R]$, where $R$ is the curvature of a connection on $E$. @ArcticChar

Then given a curvature $R$ on the tangent bundle, how do you get one on $\wedge^n TX$?
